# Windows phone 8 SDK environment path for Phonegap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am using Phonegap version 3.3 and installed latest visual stdio express for windows phone development.

With few hick ups I was managed to create and run android application using local environment but I couldn't find path that I can add to environment variable, so phonegap will detect that instead of trying for remote build.

I tried adding SDK paths but failed.

Please let me know if any further details is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a path to the .net directory, e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.

You can check .cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0\wp8\bin\check_reqs.js file for more details:

/* The tooling for cordova windows phone requires these commands

- in the environment PATH variable.
- - msbuild (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319)
- - git? (for dynamic cli loading of projects?)

  */